# How do I create a report in ServiceNow of all my incidents which do not have an affected CI?

Tags: servicenow

I'd like to create a report in ServiceNow to list all incidents for a specified Assignment Group which do not have any Affected CIs.

I can create a report of incidents that do have Affected CIs using the task_ci table, but entries are only added to that table if a CI is affected. Is there a way to list incidents that do not appear in this table?

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to do this directly on the List view if you have list v3 plugin enabled in your instance.

You can navigate to the incident list view and apply this filter on the related list
[image: Related list filter]

Make sure you specify the condition for Related list as Affected CIs Equal to 0

Comment: ServiceNow abandoned List v3 with the release of London in August, 2018 and it has been unavailable for new customers since that time. the latest ServiceNow version is Quebec.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Report Designer interface that was introduced in Jakarta, you can add filters on Relationships.

Simply add the relationship filter for no Affected CIs (you do not need any conditions) under the main filter on the Incident table. (refer screenshot below)

The ability to report on record relationships is not available without using the Report Designer.

For future ServiceNow questions, you're more likely to get an answer by creating a community account and posting there: https://community.servicenow.com

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6YNZ.png)